# python package name change but other dependency pulls older name

Tags: python, pip

I have a scenario where a package name is changed for a specific functionality but a dependent package uses an old name so during pip install both get installed. Is there a way to specify a package overrides another package?

My Project Depends on
packageA_custom (pip package name is packageA_custom is created from packageA)
packageB

PackageB depends on packageA

What I would like is some way to tell pip that packageA_custom replaces packageA so both are not installed. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: @drum [`psycopg2-binary`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) vs [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/). Just a well-known example.

Comment: "*Is there a way to specify a package overrides another package?*" Alas, no.